# How to make an element take up two columns

Tags: css

I have a four column layout set up with column-count —not with a table— and I want to make the first paragraph to span over two columns.

Here's what I've got

```
<div>
    <p>I want this first paragraph to be two columns wide</p>
    <p>The rest of the content should continue to follow the 4 column set up.</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
    <p>blah</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{ column-count: 4; }
div :first-child{ column-span:all; width: 50%; }
```

but the rest of columns start from the bottom of this first paragraph and do not go over it's right side. I aim to achieve something like [this](http://typophile.com/files/add-title_5591.jpg).

Please help

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or just put in the entire layout in the question?

Comment: @AbhayKumar, I've added more information. Thanks for the interest!

Comment: add display:inline-block to p tag

Comment: It doesn't work, because the p overflows from the first column and is not displayed in the second one.

Comment: The example is a 'print style ' layout not yet achievable with CSS (AFAIK). CSS Regions are coming but that is what is required here, I believe.